# How to solve Unknown host 'cm.crashlytics.com' Issue showing up in Gradle while building the APK?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-build

I was trying to build a release variant of my App. While building the apk Gradle is showing this error `Unknown host 'cm.crashlytics.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.`

I am using Gradle version `5.4.1` and plugin `3.5.3`

Gradle dependency for crashlytics: `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01`
I know this is now deprecated. But I tried with the latest. Still no luck. Also, I tested the auto-detection proxy settings and almost everything I could find from similar queries in the stack overflow.

Gradle shows this issue only on the creation of a release build.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade your crashlytics dependencies to latest version as firebase is now suggesting to upgrade your dependencies to 17.0.0+. The following are my dependencies and apk got build

## in build.gradle (`android/build.gradle`)

- Project-level changes

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
     classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

## in build.gradle (`android/app/build.gradle`)

- App-level changes

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Still getting the same error

Comment: Updating plugins version to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1' helped me to fix this.

Comment: +1 for @Pavel's suggestion to update plugin version to 2.4.1. It worked for me ! My version was quite old 2.0.x.

Comment: awesome this worked for me. I had to change my gradle build and not just crashlytics only.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel this change solved my issue too